# Metabase cannot connect PostgreSQL in my local environment on mac

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I am a newbie to both Metabase and PostgreSQL, and I have installed Metabase and PostgreSQL on my mac, but Metabase connected PostgreSQl failed, the error is

> java.net.UnknownHostException: 127.0.0.1.

I didn't use docker.

Here is info about Metabase configuration.

[image: Metabase configuration]

Here is what I try to fix the problem.

1. I have try to connect to PostgreSQL on command line `psql {database name}`
2. I have try change the hostname to `localhost` , but the same value.

Comment: Does connecting through `psql`  work?

Comment: Check if you have got `127.0.0.1` entry in `/etc/hosts`

Comment: Yes, I have check psql {my database name} and it worked.

Comment: I check my /etc/hosts and it did have entry about 127.0.0.1